# Custom headers in public JWKs request for Spring Security OpenID Connect

Tags: spring, security, openid-connect, oam, oracle-access-manager

I'm using Oracle's OAM as an authentication provider. Our set-up mandates that the request to public JWKs endpoint (the one that you set with .jwkSetUri()) had a custom header:

`x-oauth-identity-domain-name: AppSpecificDomainName`

So far I was not able to find a proper parameter configuration in the Spring Security OpenID Connect framework.

I use Spring Security 5.8.4

I was able to make a dirty workaround to at least verify my set-up.
I copied the source-code of the RestTempate class to exact same packege that is has in the Spring framework so that it would get class-loaded first.

Then I've modified the

```java
protected <T> T doExecute(URI url, @Nullable HttpMethod method, @Nullable RequestCallback requestCallback, @Nullable ResponseExtractor<T> responseExtractor);
```

method and added header injection code:

```java
    ...
    ClientHttpRequest request = createRequest(url, method);

    // Inject custom headers if this is a security-related outbound call
    if (url.toString().startsWith("https://access.mycompany.com")) {
        request.getHeaders().add("x-oauth-identity-domain-name", "AppSpecificDomainName");
    }
    ...
```

but clearly I want a cleaner solution. Since this one is hardly maintainable.